# How to simulate comma keypress with meta key in javascript

Tags: javascript, keypress, keystroke, simulate

I'm using a chrome plugin in my Mac OS which executes javascript automatically when a page loads.
I'm able to simulate single keystroke easily.

But I need to simulate multiple keystrokes at a time ("Command"+",")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically)

Comment: @CerebralFart, That link too provides only single keystroke solution, whereas my requirement is to simulate 2 keystrokes at a time simultaneously

Comment: Command isn't really a keystroke tho, you cannot pick it up independently. Instead, it is passed as the meta key modifier (similar to control, alt or shift). Also check the documentation on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Comment: In that case, consider this scenario as "simulating 'comma' along with Metakey in javascript"